# Lisp Help | Error: Duplicate binding in LOOP : (result)

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defmethod! expand-t-setclass (pcset &optional (n 12))
  :icon *PC_ICON*
  :doc "
Given any member of a t-setclass, lists every member of that t-setclass.
The optional parameter N can be used to set the number of equal steps per
octave to something other than the default of 12.

Will tolerate integers out of the mod-N range in PCSET."
  :initvals '((1 3 4) 12)
  :indoc '("pcset or list of them"
           "modulus of the pc space")
  (if (listp (first pcset))
    (expand-t-setclasses pcset)
    (let ((t-prime (t-primeform pcset n)))
      (loop with result = nil
            repeat n
            for x-pcset = pcset then (xpose x-pcset 1 n)
            unless (member x-pcset result) collect x-pcset into result
            finally return result))))


(defmethod! expand-t-setclasses (pcset &optional (n 12))
  (loop for item in pcset collect (expand-t-setclass item n)))

;-----
```

I am not too familiar with Lisp in general, and am trying to find the bug that casues this error:

ERROR: Duplicate Binding in LOOP: (result)

Answer (score 1):

You have two forms in the LOOP introducing a variable RESULT.

```
WITH result = nil
```

and

```
COLLECT ... INTO result
```

Both above create a variable binding.

I would replace the COLLECT with a form which pushes the item to the RESULT list.

```
(loop ...
      collect item into foo
      ...
      finally (return foo))
```

into

```
(loop with foo = nil
      ...
      (push item foo)
      ...
      finally (return (reverse foo)))
```

You have another error:

```
FINALLY RETURN result
```

The LOOP syntax does not support that. FINALLY expects a compound form.

Replace it with:

```
FINALLY (return result)
```

RETURN is a defined macro in Common Lisp.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Would you know what other form I may use? I'm still not too sure how to exactly correct my first error. (This is an old piece of code from an old program and I cannot contact the developer)

Comment: I tried to enter:

      (loop with foo = nil
            ;remove with result?
            repeat n
            for x-pcset = pcset then (xpose x-pcset 1 n)
            unless (member x-pcset result) (push x-pcset foo)
            finally (return (reverse foo))))))

but got the error: LOOP keyword expected in (...(push x-pcset result) finally (return (reverse result)))

Comment: If I simply got rid of "with foo = nil" and kept collect, when it compiles at each loop would it initialize at 0 each time? So I could simply get rid of that one line of code and fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think it is really defined to what result is initialized.